# How to render the p:commandButton at last row of the p:datatable?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, commandbutton

I need to render the `<p:commandButton>` at last entry of the `<p:datatable>` only .
consider if `p:datatable` having n no.of rows means i have render the `p:commandButton` at nth row  only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you better use `<f:facet name="footer">`

```
    <f:facet name="footer">  
        <p:commandButton/> 
    </f:facet>
```

But if you really insist on last row...

Try the `rowIndexVar`,  something like this :

```
<p:dataTable value="#{myBean.myList}" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" var="item">
    <p:column>
        <p:commandButton rendered="#{(rowIndex+1) eq myBean.myList.size()}"/> 
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: rendered instead of render

Comment: @user3586195 , fixed, tx

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I got the functional requirement right, but from what I understand you want to add a single commandButton at the bottom of the table, for that you might use the following inside datatable tags:

```
 <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:commandButton/>
 </f:facet>
```

Comment: i need 2 show the P:commandButton At last entry of the p:datatable